# RC series for a switching regulator compensation pin

Tags: voltage-regulator, series, passive-filter

I am using the [Viva VP2140](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2009291606_VIVA-VP2140SPG8_C782024.pdf) switching regulator in my project.

How am I supposed to calculate the RC series into the COMP pin? I have in my project the circuit from the datasheet, first page.

Comment: The datasheet does not tell. Maybe use another regulator with proper instructions how to use it?

Comment: Looks like peak current mode control, and the datasheet block diagram hints at slope compensation.  You could stabilize the loop at low bandwidth, and run a control-output and open loop gain plots.  That would give you an idea of where to place the poles and zeros.  Or you could try modelling the loop mathematically, but I didn't check to see if all the necessary info is in the datasheet.  (E.g. slope compensation ramp amt, etc)

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard of this Taiwanese brand and I am not sure if I would use that type of chip considering the poorly-documented internals. Anyway, this is a fixed-frequency current-mode switcher and you need to compensate the operational transconductance error amplifier (OTA) with a type 2 compensator. The thing is to first extract the control-to-output transfer function (TF) without the minimum information about the internal feedback path. What is missing is the following:

- we have to recalculate the value of the internal sense resistance as it sets the gain of the power stage.
- we don't have the value of the internal "current-sense amplifier" gain. The data-sheet (DS) seems to state a "error amplifier voltage gain" of 400. Could it be that gain?
- the internal OTA has a transconductance of 500 µS
- it seems that COMP pin is internally divided by 3.3 as stated by the \$G_{CS}\$ parameter but I'm speculating here.
- then we need to know what value of the COMP pin corresponds to the maximum current setpoint. With that value in hand and knowing the internal current-sense amplifier gain, we can determine the internal sense resistance value knowing a maximum peak of 4.3 A.

Unfortunately, these information are missing and you cannot extract them without asking to the chip designer. Once you have this sense resistance and the rest of the chain, you can simulate the circuit and obtain the control-to-output TF. Below is an example with a SIMPLIS buck from my 80+ ready-made [templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) freely available from my [webpage](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Spice.htm):

[image]

From this simulation circuit, you obtain the control-to-output transfer function from the COMP pin to \$V_{out}\$. Read the gain and phase curve to feed the left-side macro (Gfc and PS in the top) then the program will automate the compensator components for you:

[image]

You can always try the components values I have found for an attempt to stabilize the converter on the bench, but, honestly, I would keep away from this type of part and use a well-documented component from a known brand in power conversion: there are plenty to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem with another manufacturer a month or two ago, they were able to provide me with a spreadsheet after contacting them. Another option would be to acquire a spice file if available. The only option after that would be to get an eval board and play with different values and send square waves through it and [compensate it manually](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZ1MFzjFvIU&ab_channel=GoCircuits) (which would require changing components or using variable components).

Comment: If I may, the video (and the TI AN) shows an over-simplistic way for compensating a power supply and going that way is a recipe for failure in production. If can be done for debugging purposes but not for qualifying a board: you *must* measure the compensated loop gain with a frequency-response analyzer (FRA) to assess margins and check robustness against components variations (lot-to-lot, temperature etc.). A transient response is certainly part of the stabilization exercise, but it cannot replace a proper analysis and measurement in the end.

Comment: I agree, but some companies provide no support and no documentation, so that route is not possible. Some designers don't need their devices to work all the time because they are going into cheap worthless electronics so they get cheap converters

Comment: I understand your comment *Voltage Spike* and I believe this approach is ok for hobbyists who can't access a proper FRA. That being said, this example conveys a good message: a designer must carefully read the specifications and make sure the data-sheet contains enough data for a reliable design before solely considering the component price. That is true for any component, passive or active I would say.

Comment: I had to go with a POE converter once because of the price and configuration, the company wouldn't provide any info on compensation but we had to go with it because of the price