# Stability modelling of LT1534

Tags: stability, royer

I am working on a high voltage supply (6kV, 100uA) using a Royer current driven oscillator with a transformer and a capacitor multiplier (ratio 6x). The LT1534 switching regulator will be used, see datasheet and application note (includes a Royer oscillator but not a capacitor multiplier, see p.4):

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1534fa.pdf

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN118fb.pdf

I am trying to understand how stability can be controlled by frequency compensation without trial and error. As I understand the description in the datasheet (p.11), Cvc2 has nothing to do with stability and is there for ripple reduction only. Stability is controlled by Rvc and Cvc. These look like a snubber, perhaps.

How can I determine the values of Rvc and Cvc without blind trial and error attempts?

Any ideas how the open loop can be simplified for simulating and/or understanding in order to check for gain and phase margins (I don't know what to do with the switching action and capacitor multiplier)?

Comment: If you want to avoid trial and error - and that is the correct way to do thing - then you first need the *control-to-output* transfer function of your converter, e.g. how a stimulus applied to the control pin propagates in the circuit to form the response you want on the output. The ratio of the response to the stimulus is the transfer function of the power stage. Once in hand, you can think of a compensation strategy. Have a look at a recent [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641697/rc-series-for-a-switching-regulator-compensation-pin/641712#641712) I gave on SE.

Comment: It's permissible to post circuit images from data sheets but, it's usually mandatory to post your actual schematic including the multipliers.